# Database updating but not saving

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an app with a pre-made database. I want to change an entry in this database and save it, but I'm running into some trouble. I have a DatabaseHelper with the following method inside:

```
public void updateStats(int rowId, int correct, int attempts) {
        //Method for updating the stats after a question is answered

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put("CORRECT", correct);
        args.put("ATTEMPTS", attempts);
        db.update("CHARACTERS", args, "_id=" + rowId, null);

        Cursor c = db.query("CHARACTERS", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToPosition(rowId-1);
        Log.d("database", "test - " + String.valueOf(c.getInt(0)));

        db.close();

    }
```

It's seems to be running the update fine, because the query is showing that the change has been made in the log. But it's the app is reverting back to the original database when I end the activity.

My knowledge of using databases in Android is patchy, so I'm probably missing something simple. Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: see http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/. may this help you.

Comment: could you post your database path?

Comment: @Deen Sure: "/data/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+"databases/";

Comment: Did you check your database located inside your package folder?

Comment: @Deen Yeah, I'm pretty sure its in the right place. I've been pulling it from the emulator in Eclipse so I can check if there were any changes.

Comment: try to clean your project and run it after reinstalling the application. may be work.else post your log report for the successfull update

Answer (score 0):

please try to use this

```
ContentValues dataToInsert = new ContentValues();
                            dataToInsert.put(ALBUM_IS_COMPLETE, "true");
                            String where = "album_id=?";
                            String[] whereArgs = {albumid};
                            try
                                {
                                    openDataBase();
                                    myDataBase.update(DATABASE_ALBUM_TABLE, dataToInsert, where, whereArgs);
                                }
                            catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                }
```

hope this will help you

Comment: I'm confused, isn't that essentially the same technique as the code i posted?

Comment: are you updating your database from the only one location?

Comment: is your database filled which you are copying on the location?